# C# and Java : 3 / 2 * 3.2 = 3.2, why?

Tags: c#, java

Conside the following for C# and Java,

```
double d = 3 / 2 * 3.2;
```

Java

```
System.out.println(d); // 3.2
```

C#

```
Console.WriteLine(d); //3.2
```

It skip the 3/2,

We know that the correct answer should be 4.8

if i change to

```
double d = 3.00 / 2 * 3.2;
```

I can get 4.8,

So i want to ask, if (3 / 2 * 3.2) is illegal , why eclipse and vs2008 have no error?
And how to prevent this problem in both C# and Java?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`3 / 2` is considered as an integer division, so the result comes out to be `1`.

Then, performing a multiplication between `1` and `3.2` causes the integer `1` to be promoted to floating point `1`, resulting in `3.2`.

The idea is:

```
// Both "3" and "2" are integers, so integer division is performed.
3 / 2 == 1

// "3.2" is a floating point value, while "1" is an integer, so "1" is
// promoted to an floating point value.
1 * 3.2  -->  1.0 * 3.2 == 3.2
```

When typing `2.0`, the decimal point tells Java to consider the literal as a floating point value (in this case, a `double`), so the result of the calculation is `4.8` as expected. Without the decimal point, the value is a integer literal.

It is not an error, but an issue with how the literals are handled.

The following links have more information:

- [Primitive Data Types](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) from [The Java Tutorials](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/index.html).
- [Conversions and Promotions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html) from [The Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html).

Answer (score 25):

`3/2` is Integer division, whose result is `1`.

`1 * 3.2` equals `3.2`, which is the result you receive.

This is a proper well-defined formula with well-defined expected results, hence no error by the compiler. Use `3.00`, it's the best straightforward way to force the compiler to use floating point math.

From [Thorbjørn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53897/thorbjorn-ravn-andersen)'s answer: another option is to standardize all your floating point calculations by starting with `1.0*`, in your example it would be `1.0*3/2*3.2`.

Comment: Multiplication is communicative with division, no matter if you're using "real" math or not. It doesn't have higher priority anywhere.

Comment: -1: The operations in this calculation are usually calculated from left to right. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B

Comment: I think the confusion here comes from the fact that multiplication commonly occurs within the numerator or denominator in algebra. Or PEMDAS.

Comment: @Williham Totland: Haha, *commutative* ;)

Comment: @sztomi... and he meant *associative* anyhow - division isn't commutative ;-)

Answer (score 7):

It's perfectly legal, but 3/2 is an integer division (which is like doing the division but then choosing the number nearest to 0 (in some languages -infinity)). You need to give the compiler some kind of "hint" want division you want to do.

You can simply avoid it by writing

```
3.0 / 2 * 3.2          or      3 / 2.0 * 3.2
3.0 / 2.0 * 3.2
3d / 2d * 3.2 (C#)
(double)3 / 2 * 3.2
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to be CERTAIN that a calculation happens with decimals instead of integers, then either start with

```
 1.0 * 3 / 2 * 3.2
```

or tell the compiler that the first number is a real/double:

```
3d / 2 * 3.2
```

Comment: +1 for starting with 1.0, very clean

Answer (score 3):

When dividing one integer literal with another, the entire expression is treated at integer division: `3/2` as such becomes 1; not 1.5 (because it's all integers). Not until the next part, `1 * 3.2` is the integer promoted to a double; and as such, not until that point does it actually become `1.0`.

EDIT: There's no error flagged because it isn't illegal.

Answer (score 1):

`3 / 2` is the first operation performed.

Both `3` and `2` are integers. When two `int`s are divided, the answer is an `int` (in this case, the answer is `1`).

So from `3 / 2 * 3.2` you end up with `1 * 3.2`. When you multiply an `int` and a `float`, the result will be promoted to a `float`. So the answer is `3.2`.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to casting and number type issues.

In C# (and Java as it seems too) 3 and 2 are both integer values so the division '3 / 2' is an integer division which leads to an integer 1.

Since 3.2 is a floating point value the integer result of the division is converted to a floating point value and multiplicated after that and since 1 * 3.2 is 3.2 that'sd the result.

There is no code error in this so that's why Java and C# accept this.

The safest way would always be to tell the compiler that you need floating point values here by using

3.0 / 2.0 * 3.2

This works in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

In C#

```
3d / 2d * 3.2
```

As stated before